# OmniFaces complains about missing CDI and empty beans.xml

Tags: jsf, cdi, tomcat8, omnifaces

I like to add omnifaces to my tomcat8 webapp but omnifaces seems to complain either about a missing CDI implementation or about not being able to parse beans.xml (some SAXParserException). Currently I have the following libraries under WEB-INF/lib:

- BootsFaces-OSP-0.8.1-dist-default.jar
- cdi-api-1.2.jar
- javax.el-api-3.0.1-b04.jar
- javax.inject-1.jar
- javax.interceptor-api-1.2.jar
- jsf-api-2.2.11.jar
- jsf-impl-2.2.11.jar
- jstl-1.2.jar
- omnifaces-2.2.jar
- primefaces-5.3.jar
- weld-core-2.3.3.Final.jar
- weld-servlet-2.3.3.Final.jar
- weld-servlet-core-2.3.3.Final.jar

Currently I have two issues with this setup:

1. a real emtpy beans.xml leads to the "nope, please install CDI" error
2. the following "empty" beans.xml leads to a "cannot parse beans.xml" error

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee  http://xmlns.jcp.org /xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_2.xsd"
   bean-discovery-mode="annotated"></beans>
   ```

The [documentation](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html) how to install CDI is from 2013 which is kind of outdated in my eyes.

What is wrong or missing in my setup and where to read on how to get omnifaces running in tomcat8?

Comment: The documentation was last updated Jan 2015 (Weld 2.2.9). It's still applicable on Weld 2.3.2, I just tried (and updated blog). You only have a lot of unnecessary, duplicate and conflicting weld/cdi JAR files. Not sure why you mixed them all. Get rid of them all and retry as per the blog. As stated in the blog, only weld-servlet is sufficient (thus NOT cdi-api, javax.inject, javax.interceptor, weld-core, weld-servlet-core).

Comment: Maybe better to switch to TomEE or some other Java EE container to prevent all this custom stuff...

Comment: Ok, thanks! I solved it with maven downloading the required libraries and getting the dependencies right. If we happen to get along with all this custom stuff someday software development will be enjoyable :)